# convert object to array of objects

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, arrays, serialization

I have the following javascript object being returned from a WCF call, this has been serialized from a dictionary object, which removed the Key/Value properties

```
Object { 7="XXX", 9="YYY" }
```

I want to convert this javascript in to the following array, with result being

```
[Object { Key=7, Value="XXX"}, Object { Key=9, Value="YYY"}]
```

I am working with the jquery client side library.

Anyone know how I can convert the object to an array of objects with Key/Value properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a reusable function that'll solve your problem:

```js
var bad = {
  7: "XXX",
  9: "YYY"
};

function fix(input) {
  var output = [];

  for (var index in input) {
    output.push({
      "KEY": index,
      "VALUE": input[index]
    });
  }

  return output;
}

// [Object { Key=7, Value="XXX"}, Object { Key=9, Value="YYY"}]
var good = fix(bad);

console.log(good)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var output = [];

for (var key in result) {
  output.push({ Key: key, Value: result[key] });
}
```

Where `result` is your WCF result. Remember, javascript objects are essentially maps, so where I can do `obj.Name`, I can also do `obj["Name"]`, and I can enumerate over the members in the map, e.g.:  `for (var prop in obj) { // Stuff`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = { "7": "XXX", "9": "YYY" }

var array = [];

for(var key in a){ array.push({key: key, value: a[key]}) }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, you could take the entries of the object and map the key/value pairs.

```js
var object = { 7: "XXX", 9: "YYY" },
    array = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
        
console.log(array);
```