# Convert javascript object to array of individual objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have the following object:

```
{English: 4, Math: 5, CompSci: 6}
```

How can I convert it to an array of objects, like:

```
[{English: 4}, {Math: 5}, {CompSci: 6}]
```

Can't find the answer anywhere. Thanks!!

Comment: Show us what you've tried, some problems you're facing (specific ones) and we'll gladly help.

Comment: To add what @AndrewL is saying, you need to show us that you actually tried something first. Show us your code that failed, and we will help you figure out why it failed and how to solve your problem.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Also, this is pretty much a duplicate of [convert object to array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6586189/218196).

Comment: More sensible/useful structure of `object` would be `{subject:SUBJECT_NAME, code:SUBJECT_CODE}`

Answer (score 11):

> Use [**`Array#forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over [**`Object.keys(YOUR_OBJECT)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var input = {
  English: 4,
  Math: 5,
  CompSci: 6
};
var op = [];
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = input[key];
  op.push(obj); //push newly created object in `op`array
});
console.log(op);
```

Comment: Great answer, just don't like the fact that the asker is asking for someone to spoon-feed them.

Comment: Thanks Rayon.  Spent 3 hours last night and the best I could do was make nested arrays.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

With newer JS, you could take [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and map single properties.

```js
var object = { English: 4, Math: 5, CompSci: 6 },
    array = Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over each of the keys in the object.

```js
var oldObject = {English: 4, Math: 5, CompSci: 6};
var newArray = [];

// Loop over each key in the object
for (var key in oldObject) {
    // Create a temp object
    var temp = {};
    
    // Set the key of temp
    temp[key] = oldObject[key]

    // Push it to the array
    newArray.push(temp);
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly assign object by `{}` but you must use `[]` quote for key value if not that will not worked

```
 var obj = {English: 4, Math: 5, CompSci: 6};
 var n_obj = [];
 for(var i in obj){
    n_obj.push({[i]:obj[i]});
 }
 console.log(n_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the object into an array of key-value pairs using `Object.entries` and then map this array to smaller object created using `Object.fromEntries` from each individual key-value pair (the key part here is the wrapping in another array before passing to `fromEntries`):

```
Object.entries(obj).map(e => Object.fromEntries([e]))
```

The reverse way is similar: We create a big object using `Object.fromEntries`, and we pass in an array of key-value pairs. This array is created by flat-mapping (i.e. eliminating on extra layer of arrays) the array of objects to an array of key-value pairs we get from calling `Object.entries` on each small object. The key here is the *flat*-mapping, without it we would get an array of arrays of key-value pairs because we added that extra layer in the other conversion to separate the properties.

```
Object.fromEntries(arr.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/".*"\:.*(?=,|})/`, `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/,/`, `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `"},{"`, `JSON.parse()`

```js
var obj = {English: 4, Math: 5, CompSci: 6};
var res = JSON.parse("[{" 
          + JSON.stringify(obj)
            .match(/".*"\:.*(?=,|})/g)[0]
            .split(/,/)
            .join("},{") 
          + "}]");
console.log(res);
```