# How do I convert an object into an array of objects where the objects in the array should be the key value pairs of the original object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the below object

```
input = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

I want to covert it into the following

```
Output = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
```

Also provide solution to vice versa i.e. array of objects to object.

I have tried using built-in methods like Object.entries but not getting the perfect solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+convert+object+to+object+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `Object.entries(obj).map(e => Object.fromEntries([e]))`, `Object.fromEntries(arr.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o)))`

Comment: The format in this question is different than in the supposed duplicate

Comment: I answered in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75322735/1871033

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` to get key/value tuples and format them as you need:

```js
const input = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
const res = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` to get the `key` and `value` pair and then form the object from them.

And to convert the obj from an array, you can just iterate to the array and create an object from them.

You can check this solution.

```js
input = {a:1, b:2, c:3}

function obj2arr(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
        return {[key]: value}
    })
}

function arr2obj(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((resObj, obj) => {
        return {...resObj, ...obj};
    }, {});
}

const arr = obj2arr(input);
const obj = arr2obj(arr);

console.log(arr);
console.log(obj);
```